# Findbugs to use rank instead of priority in Jenkins

Tags: java, testing, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, findbugs

I'm setting up a Jenkins server with Sonar for code analysis and coverage with FindBugs, Cobertura and PMD.

Then I was asked to config a job in it that runs tests for a project and if Findbugs find some  scary or worst problem then the build results in failure.

After some googling I came up to [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FindBugs+Plugin) where it says

> Release 4.26
>
> Added option to either use FindBugs bug priority or rank when mapping the plug-in warning priorities

I thought that with this I could set ranks in thresholds seen in this image

[image: Configuring a task: publishing Findbugs analysis]

So, I would like to know if it's possible to do what I was asked to and, if so, how to do it. And if I got it wrong, what's "use rank as priority" stands for?

Comment: Searching Google for [Findbugs Rank] returns http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/findbugs2.html which describes "bug rank" as a new feature and what its relationship to priority is.

Comment: I've already seen that. My question persists: how do I suppose to use this in those thresholds?